# How do I scrape using Python and BeautifulSoup - Dealing with a Table using Javascript

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn how to scrape info using Python, and unfortunately i'm having a lot of trouble here. The issue i'm dealing with is that the information I want *doesn't seem to be* contained in the page source, it only appears after you check one of the boxes.

The url in question is: http://www.ncix.com/openbox/
and for example, i want all the information that appears on the page after you check "Video Cards (20)" under "Categories." When i look at the page source it appears there's a script called submitformfilter() that looks like this:

```
function submitformfilter()
{
var querystring = "dofilter=1";
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function()
{
querystring = querystring + '&'+$(this).attr("name")+'='+$(this).val()
}
);
if($("#promokw").val() !="")
{
querystring =   querystring+'&promokw='+ $("#promokw").val();
}
$.getJSON("http://www.ncix.com/promo/openboxfilter.cfm?jsoncallback=?&"+querystring);
}
function dosearch()
{
if($("#promokw").val() =="")
{
alert("Please enter the keyword.");
return false;
}
submitformfilter();
return false;
}
```

I have no idea how to parse the data i want in this case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You won't be able to trigger javascript on page with beautifulsoup. Use e.g. the selenium web driver with a headless browser like phantomJS to actually bring the page in the state you want it to be, then scrape it.

Comment: @Mr.Yetti, what does it mean to be a "headless browser"? Would it work if i used Chrome/Firefox drivers for Selenium?

Comment: @Ambushes, you don't need selenium, you just have to mimic the ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to post data, in particular the `minorcatid` which relates to the video cards:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = {"dofilter": "1",
        "minorcatid": ""}
```

# not necessarily essential  but good to at least add a user-agent
   headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    # use bs4 to get the minorcatid programmatically
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("http://www.ncix.com/openbox/").content, "lxml")
    _id = soup.select_one("img[alt^=Video]")["src"].rsplit("/", 1)[1][:-4]
    data["minorcatid"] = _id
    resp = s.post("http://www.ncix.com/promo/openboxfilter.cfm", data=data, headers=headers).text

    print(resp)
```

Which would give you the data from the callback, there is more form data but we get away with just passing the id.

You can see in chrome tools exactly what happens when you select the box:

[image]

The response is the same as you see in the dev console:

[image]

We pull the id from the img tag relating to Video Cards by parsing the src attribute from the original page:

```
<img src="http://img.ncix.com/categoryimages/108.jpg" width="110" height="55" title="Video Cards" alt="Video Cards">
```

The data is escaped when we get it so to get it into a nicer format we can decode using *unicode_escape*, after doing that we can parse the table and get whatever you want, for example the anchor tags than contain the link to each and the description:

```
In [6]: with requests.Session() as s:
   ...:         soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("http://www.ncix.com/openbox/").content, "lxml")
   ...:         _id = soup.select_one("img[alt^=Video]")["src"].rsplit("/", 1)[1][:-4]
   ...:         print(_id)
   ...:         data["minorcatid"] = _id
   ...:         resp = s.post("http://www.ncix.com/promo/openboxfilter.cfm", data=data, headers=headers).content.decode("unicode_escape")
   ...:         soup2 = BeautifulSoup(resp.replace(r'\""', ''), "lxml")
   ...:         for tr in soup2.select("table tr"):
   ...:                 print(tr.select_one("div a[title^=SKU]"))   ...:         


108
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/gigabyte-radeon-r9-fury-x-42-110438.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 110438
Mfr part #: GV%2DR9FURYX%2D4GD%2DB">GIGABYTE Radeon R9 Fury X 1050MHZ 4GB 1GHz HBM HDMI DISPLAYPORTX3 PCI-E Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/gigabyte-geforce-gtx-970-oc-6d-102012.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 102012
Mfr part #: GV%2DN970WF3OC%2D4GD">GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 970 OC 1253 MHz 4GB 7.0GHZ GDDR5 2xDVI HDMI DisplayPort PCI-E Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/sapphire-radeon-x1950-pro-dual-96-24458.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 24458
Mfr part #: 11095%2D08%2D40R">Sapphire Radeon X1950 Pro Dual 580MHZ 1GB 1.4GHZ GDDR3 PCI-E 2XDVI-I TV Out Dual GPU Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/zotac-geforce-gt-730-zone-54-129574.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 129574
Mfr part #: ZT%2D71114%2D20L">Zotac GeForce GT 730 Zone Edition 1GB 902MHZ 1600MHz DDR3 DirectX 12 DVI + HDMI + VGA Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/club3d-radeon-r9-285-royal-43-101460.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 101460
Mfr part #: CGAX%2DR92856">CLUB3D Radeon R9 285 Royal Queen 945MHZ 2GB 5.5GHZ GDDR5 2xDVI HDMI DisplayPort PCI-E Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/soltek-refurbished-nvidia-fx5600-agp8x-c6-11182.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 11182
Mfr part #: SL%2D5600%2DXD%2DR">SOLTEK REFURBISHED nVIDIA FX5600 AGP8X /128BIT/128MB DDR *30DAY WARRANTY* CARD ONLY</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/chaintech-apogee-geforce-6800-gt-ad-12556.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 12556
Mfr part #: AA6800G">Chaintech APOGEE GeForce 6800 GT 256MB DDR3 AGP8X VGA DVI-I TV Out Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/sapphire-radeon-x800-gto2-256mb-1f-17166.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 17166
Mfr part #: 102%2DA47466%2D11%2DAT%20%2821067%2D01%2D20%29">Sapphire Radeon X800 GTO2 256MB GDDR3 PCI-E Dual DVI VIVO OEM Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/sapphire-radeon-x1600-pro-advantage-de-21813.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 21813
Mfr part #: 88%2D8C87%2D11%2DSA">Sapphire Radeon X1600 Pro Advantage PCI-E 256MB DDR VGA DVI-I TV Out Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/sapphire-radeon-hd-5850-725mhz-96-50790.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 50790
Mfr part #: 21162%2D00%2D40R">Sapphire Radeon HD 5850 725MHZ 1GB 4.0GHZ GDDR5 PCI-E Display Port 2XDVI HDMI DirectX 11 Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/sapphire-radeon-hd-6570-650mhz-1b-82646.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 82646
Mfr part #: 11191%2D03%2D20G">Sapphire Radeon HD 6570 650MHZ 512MB 4GHZ GDDR5 DVI HDMI PCI-E Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/sapphire-radeon-r9-fury-core-93-122143.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 122143
Mfr part #: 11247%2D03%2D40G">Sapphire Radeon R9 Fury Core 1050MHZ 4G HBM PCI-E HDMI/DVI-D Triple DP TRI-X OC+ (UEFI) Graphic Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/bfg-geforce-7600gs-oc-420mhz-cc-18204.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 18204
Mfr part #: BFGR76256GSOCE">BFG GeForce 7600GS OC 420MHZ PCI-E 256MB 800MHZ DDR2 VGA DVI-I HDTV Out Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/xfx-geforce-7800gtx-450mhz-256mb-f4-15636.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 15636
Mfr part #: PV%2DT70F%2DUNF7">XFX GeForce 7800GTX 450MHZ 256MB 256BIT 1.25GHZ DDR3 PCI-E Dual DVI-I TV-OUT Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/xfx-geforce-7600-gs-400mhz-6c-21791.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 21791
Mfr part #: PVT73PYDJ3">XFX GeForce 7600 GS 400MHZ PCI-E 512MB 128BIT 533MHZ DDR2 VGA DVI-I HDTV Out Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/xfx-radeon-r7-260x-dual-74-95523.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 95523
Mfr part #: R7%2D260X%2DCDF4">XFX Radeon R7 260X Dual Fan OC 1.1GHZ 2GB GDDR5 2xDVI HDMI DisplayPort PCI-E Video Card R7-260X-CDF4</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/evga-geforce-gtx-470-superclocked-8c-53391.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 53391
Mfr part #: 012%2DP3%2D1475%2DAR">EVGA GeForce GTX 470 SUPERCLOCKED+ 625MHZ Fermi 1280MB 3.4GHZ GDDR5 2XDVI Mini-HDMI PCI-E Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/evga-e-geforce-8600gt-540mhz-256mb-31-23715.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 23715
Mfr part #: 256%2DP2%2DN751%2DTR">EVGA E-GEFORCE 8600GT 540MHZ 256MB 1.4GHZ GDDR3 PCI-E Dual DVI-I HDTV Out DIRECTX10 Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/evga-e-geforce-8600gt-540mhz-512mb-2e-26168.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 26168
Mfr part #: 512%2DP2%2DN756%2DTR">EVGA E-GEFORCE 8600GT 540MHZ 512MB 800HZ DDR2 PCI-E VGA DVI-I HDTV Out DIRECTX10 Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/evga-e-geforce-7600-gt-co-13-17949.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 17949
Mfr part #: 256%2DP2%2DN555">EVGA E-GEFORCE 7600 GT CO Superclocked 580MHZ PCI-E 256MB 1.5GHZ GDDR3 Dual DVI HDTV Out Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/evga-geforce-gtx-980-4gb-5e-102000.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 102000
Mfr part #: 04G%2DP4%2D2982%2DKR">EVGA GeForce GTX 980 4GB Super Clocked GAMING Silent Cooling 1241MHZ Boost 1342MHZ Graphics Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/gigabyte-geforce-gtx-960-g1-73-108014.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 108014
Mfr part #: GV%2DN960G1%20GAMING%2D4GD">GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 960 G1 1307MHZ 4GB 7.0GHZ GDDR5 DVI HDMI 3xDisplayPort PCI-E Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/powercolor-radeon-hd-7870-pcs-70-78372.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 78372
Mfr part #: AX7870%202GBD5%2D2DHPPV3E">Powercolor Radeon HD 7870 PCS+ MYST.(TAHITI LE) 2GB 6Gbps GDDR5 DVI HDMI 2XMINIDP PCI-E Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/powercolor-radeon-hd-3850-pcs-f8-29730.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 29730
Mfr part #: AG3850%20512MD3%2DP">Powercolor Radeon HD 3850 PCs 668MHZ 512MB 1.65GHZ GDDR3 AGP 2XDVI HDTV Out Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/msi-geforce-gtx-580-twin-79-58685.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 58685
Mfr part #: N580GTX%20Twin%20Frozr%20II%2FOC">MSI GeForce GTX 580 Twin Frozr II OC 800MHZ 1536MB GDDR5 2xDVI Mini-HDMI PCI-E DirectX 11 Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/gigabyte-radeon-hd-rx3870-775mhz-12-27208.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 27208
Mfr part #: GV%2DRX387512H%2DB">GIGABYTE Radeon HD RX3870 775MHZ 512MB 2.4GHZ GDDR4 Dual DVI-I HDCP HDTV Out PCI-E Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/gigabyte-radeon-hd-r7-240-bc-90927.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 90927
Mfr part #: GV%2DR724OC%2D2GI%20REV2%2E0">GIGABYTE Radeon HD R7 240 OC 900MHZ 2GB 1.8GHZ GDDR3 DVI HDMI VGA PCI-E Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/gigabyte-geforce-gtx-980-ti-ff-121258.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 121258
Mfr part #: GV%2DN98TXTREME%20W%2D6GD">GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 980 Ti Xtreme Waterforce 1317MHZ 6GB 7.2GHZ GDDR5 HDMI/3XDPORT/PCI-E Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/ati-radeon-x1900xtx-650mhz-512mb-75-17528.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 17528
Mfr part #: 100%2D435805">ATI Radeon X1900XTX 650MHZ 512MB 256BIT 1.55GHZ GDDR3 PCI-E Dual DVI-I VIVO HDTV Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/asus-geforce-8800gtx-575mhz-768mb-d2-21403.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 21403
Mfr part #: EN8800GTX%2FHTDP%2F768M">ASUS GeForce 8800GTX 575MHZ 768MB 1.8GHZ GDDR3 Dual DVI-I HDTV Out DIRECTX10 Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/asus-geforce-gtx-750-oc-84-94415.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 94415
Mfr part #: GTX750%2DPHOC%2D1GD5">ASUS GeForce GTX 750 OC 1GB GDDR5 PCI-E Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/asus-geforce-gtx-550-ti-25-59650.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 59650
Mfr part #: ENGTX550%20TI%20DC%20TOP%2FDI%2F1GD5">ASUS GeForce GTX 550 Ti DC Top 975MHZ 1GB 4.1GHZ GDDR5 DVI HDMI VGA PCI-E Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/asus-geforce-gt-520-700mhz-54-70010.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 70010
Mfr part #: ENGT520SL%2FDI%2F2GD3%28LP%29">ASUS GeForce GT 520 700MHZ 2GB 1.2GHZ DDR3 Low Profile DVI HDMI PCI-E DirectX 11 Video Card</a>
<a href="http://www.ncix.com/detail/asus-geforce-gtx-980-ti-1a-111058.htm#openbox" title="SKU: 111058
Mfr part #: STRIX%2DGTX980TI%2DDC3OC%2D6GD5%2DGAMING">ASUS GeForce GTX 980 Ti Strix 1317MHZ 6GB 7.2GHZ GDDR5 DVI HDMI 3XDISPLAYPORT PCI-E Video Card</a>
```

All data contains is the necessary from data we need to post, you can see what requests does with it by looking at the body of the request:

```
In [8]: with requests.Session() as s:
   ...:         soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("http://www.ncix.com/openbox/").content, "lxml")
   ...:         _id = soup.select_one("img[alt^=Video]")["src"].rsplit("/", 1)[1][:-4]
   ...:         data["minorcatid"] = _id
   ...:         resp = s.post("http://www.ncix.com/promo/openboxfilter.cfm", data=data, headers=headers)
   ...:         req = resp.request
   ...:         print(req.body)
   ...:     

dofilter=1&minorcatid=108
```

If anything needs to be encoded requests will take care of that for you.

Comment: @Ambushes, what parts do you not understand, do you know how ajax post requests etc.. work?

Comment: @Padriac Cunningham
Thank you so much for your elaborate answer! Unfortunately I couldn't understand all of it so i'd appreciate some elaboration:

Is the data["minorcatid"] = _id and the process of finding the value of _id necessary? I looked at the element in Chrome and found that the minorcatid value was 108 for Video Cards.  

Second, can you explain what exactly is happening in the last three lines, and the purpose of the data and headers variables?  
Thanks.

I've also never worked with AJAX / post requests before.

Comment: @Ambushes, what if the id changes? You have to post the form data which is exactly what data contains, do you understand how http requests, headers etc.. work?

Comment: Unfortunately i've never worked with this kind of thing before. If it's too difficult to explain, do you have any links i should visit to read on it?  

Also I tried running the code you provided, but print(resp) returns the following: http://puu.sh/pWc9k/8911ee6be4.png  

Is this correct? Thanks again.

Comment: @Ambushes, that link should not have been there, run the updated code. If  you want to be proficient at scraping web data you need to understand how html, and msot importantly http works. If you want an excellent book then I would highly recommend *HTTP: The Definitive* Guidehttp://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565925090.do

Comment: Also  using firebug or chrome tools  are essential tools when it comes to scraping to monitor the requests made.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No worries, even if a wrote a 5000 word essay I could not cover a fraction of what is and can be involved in the world of http and web scraping, I would really recommend that book I added in the link.

Comment: Apologize for asking again, but i tried running your code exactly and my result differed from yours (i was missing some results after parsing the table.) Any idea why this happened?  

Here is what it looks like: http://puu.sh/pWcXf/583cb48f4f.png

Comment: What are you missing?

Comment: Here is a pastebin with my result compared to yours: http://pastebin.com/McYpXscA

Comment: Chnage the line to `print(tr.select_one("div a[title^=SKU]").text)` and add that output

Comment: Here is my output when that line is changed.  
http://pastebin.com/7VKukZaH  

It's still missing a lot of results, i'm not sure as to why. I believe my code is 100% the same as the one you ran.

Comment: version of bs4 you are using? I get all the links without issue

Comment: I am using bs4 version 4.4.1 and request version 2.10.0.

Comment: Try setting `parser="html.parser"`